Would ETW tracing work in Windows XP if I use manifest-based events?
Mayby it's a silly question, but I don't find an answer.
My program use old technique to write ETW reports - WinApi ReportEvent function. Some scripts generate .mc file, prepare it with mc.exe and use it as manifest. So, after registering EventSource and other stuff everythink working great. And this method is XP compatible.
Now I have to move to manifest-based method and i don't find any information would it work on Windows XP? I mean I can execute something like MC AllCaps.man -um -z AllCapsEvents but if I load binary with this manifest on XP will if be a correct event source?
This question appears because new ETW API is Vista+.
Thank you!

You can look at the generated code if the manifest approach uses the same underlying APIs with the same flags then you should be fine.
